# Extending RelativeLayout by inflating from xml?

Tags: android, inheritance, android-relativelayout

I want to create a class named TabView which extends RelativeLayout and it is inflated from xml that contains RelativeLayout. The thing is that it doesn't seem to work as I expected. Did I do something wrong in the constructor? I know layoutInflater.inflate returns View object but what do I have to make it equal to? Any advice is apprecited!

```
private class TabView extends RelativeLayout {
    private int mIndex;

    public TabView(Context context) {
        super(context, null, R.attr.vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tabview_title_subtitle, null);
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return mIndex;
    }

    public void setTitle() {
        TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText("Followers");
    }

    public void setSubitle() {
        TextView subtitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        subtitle.setText("435");
    }
}
```

The following is tabview_title_subtitle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:text="Subtitle"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please don't add tags like Android, ios etc to your questions titles, the tags at the bottom are enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, your layout should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:text="Subtitle"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</merge>
```

In other way you'll end up with `RelativeLayout` that contains another `RelativeLayout`

Second. Inflate it like this:

```
layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tabview_title_subtitle, this);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can see the following [blog](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCustomViews/article.html) for creating and using custom views in android. 
And probably using

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_color_options, this, true);
```

instead of

```
 layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tabview_title_subtitle, null);
```

is what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tabview_title_subtitle, this);
```

to actually add the inflated view to `TabView`(right now you just inflate it and immediately discard it). Also if you want to use your custom view in a xml layout then also implement the constructor that takes a `Context` and an `AttributeSet`.